# How to create abstract class object which implements interface ( JAVA )

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

**I have an interface**

```
public interface I{
  Status getStatus();
}
```

then I have an abstract class implementing that interface

```
public abstract class C implements I{
       public Status getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

I want to access the getstatus() method from another class, I have tried

```
C status = new C();
```

but I am getting error *"Cannot instantiate the type C"*

Any help will be highly appreciated..!!
thanx.

Comment: You've got an abstract class which implements an interface. You just can't instantiate it because it's abstract - which has *nothing* to do with the fact that it implements an interface.

Comment: so, how can I access the getStatus method then?

Comment: You have to instantiate a concrete subclass of `C`, which is the normal behaviour for abstract classes. (Note that you'd need to declare a `status` variable in `C` for `C` to even compile, of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not create object for an abstract class
 Write a concrete class which extends your abstract class and use that class object to call the method

```
 class test extends c{
      ..........
     }

    c  obj1= new test();
   obj1.getStatus();
```

Comment: ... but give it a name which doesn't violate Java naming conventions, of course. And don't declare the variable to be of type `Class`, as that won't compile.

Comment: @Looser test extends c which implements I So you need to add unimplemnted methods

Comment: @javaBeginner That method was already implemented in abstract level so doesn't required,if there are any unimplemented at abstract level you should implement them in test

Comment: @Looser After I saw your code,I tried In my PC,It shows compilation error

Answer (score 4):

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.1)

```
A class type should be declared abstract only if the intent is that subclasses
can be created to complete the implementation. If the intent is simply to prevent
instantiation of a class, the proper way to express this is to declare a 
constructor of no arguments, make it private, never invoke it, and declare no
other constructors.
```

Abstract class can have not abstract methods but it must have a valid use case(like calling super from subclass). You cannot instantiate(create objects of abstract class).

**So either remove abstract keyword or create another class that extends your abstract class.**

Ans just for the record when an abstract class implements an interface you need not implement the interface methods in abstract class(though you can if your design dictates so). But in case you don't implement interface methods in the abstract class implementing it you need to implement the same in first concrete subclass of your abstract class. Also if you do implement you interface methods in abstract class then no need to implement them again in the concrete subclass of the abstract class. You can always override it though.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your   class must be `abstract`.

You cannot instantiate an `abstract class`.

What  you can do is,Let any child to extends that class and create object for that.

[Abstract Methods and Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Comment: Since you cannot create instance it directly,create a child(subclass) and  create object for that

Comment: Glad it helped :) Go through the example I linked from official docs

Answer (score 2):

You can not instantiate abstract class

Comment: So how can I access the getStatus() method then?

Comment: @AbhishekGoel its better you read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you really abstract methods in class C, then I recommend simply using a regular class. You can still extends that calls as well.

Comment: Hi and welcome to S/O! :) This would be better off as a comment, rather than as an answer - as you're not actually an swering the question. I would recommend reading [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).